# Need help with pseudocode please

Tags: binary, pseudocode

Given a binary number calculate the maximum block.
For ex:
Binary representation = 11111
Maximum block length = 5

Binary representation = 10111011
Maximum block length = 3

max block means the number of consecutive 1's or 0's. So 00010000 would have a max block of 4

Above are the only 2 examples my professor gave.
"Compute the maximum block length of the binary
representation." This is what he said. I'm assuming this includes 0s as well. I really don't know how to go about it.

This is what I have come up with:

Let B = the binary number received.
put B into A[], each digit representing an element.
assume A[0] = 1
for A.length - 1
count 1s as long as not hit zero
max = total count of 1s.
count 0s as long as not hit 1
update max if necessary
repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Here's the complete code. This gets the user input, converts the decimal number to binary, counts the maximum block of 1's and counts total 1's. There is still small bug, input should be accepted if 0 is entered and the program should work properly, but it does not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test 
{
    private static int decimalNumber = 0;
    private static String binaryNumber = "";
    // Get user input and return it
    // Check to make sure the input received is >= 0
    // If not > 0 then ask for input again
    private static void getInput()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner to get user input
        System.out.println("Please type in a number >= 0"); // Tells user to type a number > 0
        decimalNumber = sc.nextInt(); // Stores the input in decimalNumber
        if(decimalNumber < 0)   // Loop to make sure input received is > 0
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect input received"); // Tells the user input received was incorrect.
        }
    }

    private static void toBinary() 
    {
        while (decimalNumber != 0) 
        {
            if (binaryNumber.length() % 5 == 0) 
            {
                binaryNumber = "" + binaryNumber;
            }
            binaryNumber = (decimalNumber % 2) + binaryNumber;
            decimalNumber /= 2;
        }
        System.out.println("Binary representation = " + binaryNumber);
    }

    public static void countOnes()
    {
        int ones = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < binaryNumber.length(); i++)
        {
            if(binaryNumber.charAt(i) == '1')
            {
                ones++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No. of 1’s in the binary representation = " + ones);
    }

    public static void maximumBlock()
    {
        int block = 0;
        int maxBlock = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < binaryNumber.length(); i++)
        {
            if((binaryNumber.charAt(i) == '1') && (i < binaryNumber.length()))
            {
                block++;
                if(maxBlock < block)
                {
                    maxBlock = block;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                block = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum block length = " + maxBlock);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        getInput();
        toBinary();
        countOnes();
        maximumBlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go through the sequence, keeping track of:

- What the last number was
- The length of the current block (which gets reset if last number != current number)
- The length of the longest block so far (up to and including the current block)

Edge case you'll have to deal with is the first element, which has no predecessor, so you'll have to set the first 'last number' to that before you hit the loop, which should only iterate through from the second to the end.

Answer (score 1):

In C I would do it like this

```
int maxblock( unsigned int binary_val )
{
    int max_block = 0;
    int cur_block = 0;
    unsigned int prev_bit = 0;
    unsigned int mask = 1;
    int count = 0;
    for( count = 0; count < (sizeof(int)*8); count++ )
    {
        unsigned int this_bit = binary_val & mask;
        if( this_bit && prev_bit )
            cur_block++;
        else if( !this_bit && !prev_bit )
            cur_block++;
        else
        {
            if( cur_block > max_block )
                max_block = cur_block;
            cur_block = 1;
        }
        prev_bit = this_bit;
        mask = mask << 1;
    }
    if( cur_block > max_block )
        max_block = cur_block;
    return max_block;
}
```

Comment: thank you! i actually needed this in C :) But right now I'm working in java. Should be able to translate the code, I hope.

Comment: actually, can you translate the code into java please? I am not really familiar with C yet.

Comment: @user What part are you having trouble translating into Java? We'll help you, but we don't do it for you. Reading the first part of this should help. :) http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html